# Magento 1.6.2 -> 1.7 Upgrade leads to price index corruption

Tags: mysql, magento

I've updated magento from 1.6.2 to 1.7, everthing went smooth, apparently the site is working just fine. However I can't reidex the product prices, it looks like one of the tables is missing columns. I've tried the shell tool that's what I get:

```
Product Prices index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/app/code/community/Brim/Groupedoptions/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Grouped.php(76): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#7 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Grouped.php(48): Brim_Groupedoptions_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Grouped->_prepareGroupedProductPriceData()
#8 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Grouped->reindexAll()
#9 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#10 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#11 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#14 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/app/code/community/Brim/Groupedoptions/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Grouped.php(76): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Grouped.php(48): Brim_Groupedoptions_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Grouped->_prepareGroupedProductPriceData()
#7 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Grouped->reindexAll()
#8 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /home/thelittl/public_html/asia/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#13 {main}
```

Can't tell how this is affecting the site, IF it's affecting it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, I debugged the query and found the issue to my problem, maybe it helps someone else. I changed:

**app/code/community/Brim/Groupedoptions/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Grouped.php**

Around line 55, adding another argument there for a column that wasn't being taking in consideration:

```
'group_price'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL')
```

and done!

Answer (score 4):

This may not being a missing column issue. The  `Insert value list does not match column list` happens most often when someone passes the database abstraction layer a string when it expects and array, or an array when it expects a string.

It looks like someone, (maybe you) added some custom code in the

```
Brim_Groupedoptions
```

module.  My guess would be a class rewrite of one of the resource models used in the indexing process.  Check that the query in 
       app/code/community/Brim/Groupedoptions/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Grouped.php

on line `76` is passing in the correct number of columns and/or using the resource model methods correctly.

Comment: You are a legend sir ! my file was in a slightly different location (maybe an older version as it used to be a free module) see here and on line no 78.. Hope this help someone attempting the nightmarish magento upgrade... /app/code/local/Brim/Groupedsimple/Model/Mysql4/Indexer/Price

Comment: You made my day! We purchased Brim's extension over a year ago and therefore we have no updates. Yesterday I upgraded our test system from Magento 1.6.2.0 to 1.7.0.2 and stumbled over the price index issue. Thanks a lot! Cheers Thorsten BTW: If anyone uses Organicinternet's Simple Configuration Products extension and plan to upgrade to Magento 1.7.0.2 there should by the same issue. A fix is available at https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple.